# Json empty key with $.post node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been posting data to my nodejs server using `$.post` and it was receiving data fine till now but when I send an obj like this:

```
var myProject={
    myFirstKey:"some data here"
    mySecondKey:{s1:"some data",s2:"some more data"},
    myThirdKey:{}
}
```

on the server end when I console.log my data the first and second key is getting detected by not the third one but as soon as I populate it like this:

```
var myProject={
    myFirstKey:"some data here"
    mySecondKey:{s1:"some data",s2:"some more data"},
    myThirdKey:{t1:"some data",t2:"some more data"}
}
```

It is getting received... I don't why this is happening.

here are my definitions:

```
var express  = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

I think I may be making a simple mistake but not able to pinpoint it.

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: Aren't you missing a comma from the end of `myFirstKey:"some data here",`?

Comment: "URL encoded" is not suitable for nested data. Use another encoding scheme.